# Hibernate entities mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I have entities Unit, Employee and I want have mapping to list of Employee in Unit.

Example SQL:

```
select e.*
from wfm.WFM_EMPLOYEE e
    join wfm.wfm_position2unit p2u on p2u.UNIT_POSITION_ID=e.unit_position_id
    join wfm.WFM_POSITION p on p.POSITION_ID=p2u.POSITION_ID
    join wfm.wfm_unit u on u.UNIT_ID=p2u.UNIT_ID
where u.unit_id = 337
```

Now I have access to employees through 'nested' @OneToMany annotations:

In Unit:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WFM_UNIT", schema = AppData.WFM_SCHEMA)
public class Unit implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unit", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Position2unit> position2units;
    ...
}
```

PositionToUnit:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WFM_POSITION2UNIT", schema = AppData.WFM_SCHEMA)
public class Position2unit implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "POSITION_ID")
    private Position position;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UNIT_ID")
    private Unit unit;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "position2unit", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Employee> employees;
    ...
}
```

Employee:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WFM_EMPLOYEE", schema = AppData.WFM_SCHEMA)
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    ...
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UNIT_POSITION_ID")
    private Position2unit position2unit;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by far the easiest solution would be to add a method to Unit:

```
Collection<Employee> getEmployees() {
  final Collection<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
  for (final Position2unit p2u : position2units) {
    employees.addAll(p2u.employees);
  }
  return employees;
}
```

and forget about mapping altogether.

Comment: Yes, of course there is. But in my opinion is won't make much sense. Because implementing it would make things much more complex. For example to keep it in sync with the other relationship. You'll need to implement life-cycle methods for those. Whereas if you don't map you'll always get the right employees for each Unit. Or why would you want it to be mapped ? (no sarcasm intended here)

Comment: List of employees will be used only to display data, without manipulating.
Mapping, more elegant, I think. And so I was just interesting, there is no principle difference between mapping and method.

Comment: Well - personally I'd rather not map at all. Less coding. :-) But if you really want to, you'll have to include a method annotated with @ PostPersist, @ PostUpdate and @ PostDelete to keep the relationship in sync. Check what employees are left in the p2u's and replace those in the Unit->Employee mapping.